# Can't bring up JPA console in Intellij

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, java-ee-7

When I try to open the JPA console from the Persistence tool window in IntelliJ, it's grayed out, I have a *persistence.xml* file with the entities classes mapped out, I have data-sources also mapped out. I haven't set any properties in the persistence unit in *persistence.xml* file - what am I missing?

Intellij version: 2017.1.4

[image]

Comment: Sorry.. I can't see the image but just on case.. can you share from your persistence.xml the transaction type of your `persistence-unit` tag?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [help documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-jpa-support.html) make sure that the Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets plugin is enabled. Also JPA facet must be configured for the module (with set JPA configuration file and JPA Provided). Then you can make [JPA Console available](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-jpa-console.html#d469049e21) after associating your persistence unit with the corresponding data source.